# CSS, JavaScript , Images not loading in JSP file

Tags: java, css, jsp

I have tried to inclue css file for my page style but it's not working for me. When i checked in my browser using inspect then i found i mean inspect showing that the css file is loaded but it's not working. And it's a really spoocky situations for me!

```
 <link href="css/theme_default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I have tried like this too

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/theme_default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Following is my content tree --

```
WebContent
 -> admin
   --> common
   --> img
   --> index.jsp
   --> login.jsp
 -> css
   --> bootstrap
   --> codemirror
   --> fontawesome
   --> jquery
   --> summernote
   --> test.css
   --> theme_default.css
 -> error
   --> 404.jsp
   --> 500.jsp
 -> images
 -> js
 -> META-INF
 -> WEB-INF
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?" If you look at the styles in an inspector in a web browser, do you see any of the styles you set?

Comment: If developer tools shows that it's loaded, then it is correctly loaded. This means that maybe the content of your CSS file is invalid.

Comment: @KevinBoone Yes. It's showing my style /css file loaded but there is no any changes in the style.

Comment: Have you tried making style changes that are completely unambiguous, like setting the <body> background red (and no other styles)? It's all too easy to make a trivial syntax error in a CSS file, and find only after a lot of inspection that it isn't getting parsed.